# React - value of select element not changing with state change

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

Im working on a project where when creating a user i have to pick city,institution and department. When you pick city you get a list of institution that are in that city and when you pick institutions you get departments. What i want to achieve is when you pick another city, institution and department reset to default value. And the problem is that it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
                           <select
                            autoComplete="off"
                                name="institution"
                                value={caregiverState.institution}
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    handleChange(e);
                                    handleDepartmentQuery(e);
                                }}
                            >
                                {institutions.map((institution: IInstitution, index: number): ReactElement => {
                                    return (
                                        <option key={index} value={institution._id}>
                                            {institution.name}
                                        </option>
                                    );
                                })}
                                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                                    Select institution
                                </option>
                            </select>
```

This is state and handleChange method:

```
const [caregiverState, setCaregiverState] = useState<ICaregiver>({
        name: '',
        description: '',
        email: '',
        city: '',
        institution: '',
        department: '',
        role: 'caregiver',
    });

        const handleChange = (e): void => {
        switch (e) {
            case e.target.name === 'city':
                return setCaregiverState({
                    ...caregiverState,
                    institution: '',
                    department: '',
                });
            case e.target.name === 'institution':
                return setCaregiverState({
                    ...caregiverState,
                    department: '',
                });
            default:
                return setCaregiverState({
                    ...caregiverState,
                    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
                });
        }
    };
```

Problem is even if i change state to "" select element does't change it to :

```
  <option value="" selected disabled >
                                        Select institution
                                    </option>
```

I actually get the firstinstitution from map()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing I'm noticing is you're misusing `switch`. You're comparing `e` to `e.target.name === 'city'` which doesn't make sense (it might actually be working due to truthy checks, but its still wrong). Instead switch on `e.target.name` and only put the string in the `case`

Comment: The second thing I'm noticing is you're specifying a `selected` element, but also providing `select` a `value`. You should choose one or the other. In your case, you want the `value` prop since you are controlling the component

Comment: Switch works, e is Event element that holds name and value.

Comment: Like I said, it may work, but it's wrong. The value you pass to `switch` is used to compare against each case. You're not using it that way, you're providing a condition on each case. In reality its comparing `e` with `true` or `false` based on the condition. See the docs on [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: @BrianThompson removed selected problem still persists

Comment: Please provide a [mre]